Rails 7.2.1 with config.log_tags = [ :request_id ] results in large logs with long list of UUIDs on each request
I recently upgraded my Rails app from 6.1 to 7.2, and after doing this, I found that my logging volume for requests went up a lot. I inspected some of the logs and saw that they are looking like:
{"timestamp":"2024-09-02T23:24:50.179894Z","partial_id":"0c7e8a9d1f40e5f3f72afbdc5902394c57fec00df8b11059a416baf52af75c5f","partial_ordinal":"3","partial_last":"false","source":"stdout","log":"0-d7c0-438d-b846-e9a34c22e776] [71f04b9c-390b-4c91-842d-9aec21ad7809] [afa609b5-2d27-4af0-acf7-d83d139984e1] [ba736f8e-3205-4079-b9f2-e09b33ea0139] [fcf47b27-d7b9-4f0d-8a75-4dd82c768c6a] [be87feda-edd5-4e88-b95c-c12946f27862] [5283b64b-e11a-469c-bd5e-286441b66df8] [97261948-6313-4d47-aeb8-333c9adcdd2c] [4027194c-1d2e-4b3c-9d20-e460ef03f238] [cf4d9f9e-0c29-481d-94d4-c213041306c0] [2edfb1d1-2547-49fc-adf3-a45784c86ef0] [fb626caf-e2e0-4266-888a-8268bc38608a] [836b77b1-c8b1-4b68-90f9-33837e420121] [8a4a6f85-1353-41ef-8452-80dd3e1ff932] [885f7c74-c950-4c5c-92e0-089b13737b82] [5209b5c6-9ebd-47f1-b5ec-2a8810dd68f6] [ace995d4-80c0-4a62-a738-57fe942cc199] [29b083da-6021-4c41-9eb7-099b8f30f204] [cd528d28-6f00-4349-ac27-c917cc665af2] [81a46a49-f470-4efb-a0f7-bfa832211843] [ae80f1af-62df-4798-90fb-ca8420d5652e] [3b3748bf-6194-4c01-92a6-09399e59704f] [a13925b1-c063-4c32-8388-eef324f15d65] [e231fecc-0493-47e2-9ff7-9a90c7f8fc18] [4a46bad1-3fb1-4d80-a6c9-15d7c53554b6] [7cc71a58-bf63-47c5-b748-3bd6512a2b96] [ccf33285-9263-43b3-8a27-8aeaad70978d] [e58ae248-c3d7-49a4-9f26-e043838c6492] [f614e2e5-f03a-424e-9f48-60c38156c91f] [7d3f0ac0-91f2-43e1-89e3-efde51724018] [29af79c9-be42-4e03-ab3e-048e85096d04] [369a546a-9446-4ba9-8278-2b23596b4413] [41ff15cc-8f51-42be-94dd-19414b86c20c] [4aa3fb74-75aa-4da7-ad9f-324f365b63a4] [436e909e-5246-469d-a53c-3aa6ae9c9405] [e9c5525b-5563-4277-89af-d088526f7604] [cb6726ba-a1cd-45c3-9c76-6921747cb35e] [968cb14b-deb6-4817-9851-42ebc770852c] [b169ee34-9789-41d0-aed0-9cff878bdc23] [4c59b456-3989-4cd1-a2fb-7ab61ae2edc2] [3346db20-5289-476d-9953-b7ced8976d07] [2bf98cd9-e7a9-43aa-bf0d-a2b48bba6fc4] [9f50e6d1-c544-49ef-ab50-3e4093bfa93a] [62229e7d-35be-44d9-8cae-58de8b5d369d] [4d314af3-b963-4cb8-9b6a-846fab45dff0] [bce55508-80ed-4fca-a0f1-f379f77ab026] [32edf3b2-3fff-4415-aea8-f8949aba0b7d] [ef2c62d1-794d-4109-ac26-550eb73ee6e4] [ab601dc0-98ef-41a4-878d-961254d08689] [efca5d73-8287-45e5-9b6b-27c415c8ef06] [003fa0a5-3e40-4ef1-bfd1-c490dde90973] [75fe29fa-128c-4cc5-bb7b-da51605bd464] [eb85f678-45c6-442c-b324-64a90bfac233] [877962bd-7b6a-4afe-a09a-0e1c2ccf079e] [3ae83080-87a5-45b6-971a-0471b355a3d7] [d1384b3f-e152-4fef-ad29-402367ed997d] [4bc1ce74-c3fc-4014-94f4-970f243e8a6d] [1c8d3e41-62bd-4dd2-9692-bc26819a9d54] [17961a5f-67fe-4337-90e3-2db7ba7a2fbd] [a858d197-e877-4ebc-9346-ff18496f093f] [f1a4e0c0-e57b-4dbc-bd9d-719591ebc2cf] [f0e1b116-3a44-483c-9cad-066b7751b7ac] [00418dce-3f5f-48be-a4d1-ac306f600698] [f142dbd5-f8b1-4c76-bd67-7bbcea6bf287] [91b0747a-2a07-4fc9-9e4e-8d1e57bdb98d] [81e2918d-fad4-40b0-9aa4-1a8ac10abf8f] [8411b4fc-6e27-4f3e-acf3-f5619e406fd8] [87606f2f-d954-4532-b524-c0baec21ab31] [be90b646-4103-49cc-9ad7-9c58bb4737ee] [8b2a6984-730e-4e80-b8b9-5b012d818175] [a33a0e6a-3b67-4eeb-9056-7c506f387acb] [f68f8c4b-fbca-4621-acce-3c66ecee4e7e] [18471c8e-9cf2-43dc-b238-935280c8e893] [1a25c504-0bc1-4d10-b2a4-18a19fc2d264] [e5c6266a-31b3-4d7c-8054-47d041e99943] [a3dc1be9-8a5b-4b4a-a2d2-81ef7fe8cc3d] [a3d7a6ff-b600-416a-bee8-6559323e7bfb] [eceea7ca-96cc-4118-97a9-5dc898cfb140] [6899d3b2-29e5-4770-89dd-22df215b92b8] [66bcc9e2-b2dc-44ec-ac02-e87f9398fa85] [1c0b7229-6887-4e1a-bc84-c34727ecb424] [2298a790-c6a4-474d-b2d7-45181a590999] [5262d9e5-b37a-43f2-a327-b7a1bc4e2e8b] [0b3a8f22-5d04-4437-b7cc-4173843d4113] [3f633b9f-f409-4277-b00b-78473e292772] [5ab6dcc7-abbe-4ddb-b9e0-dd2a218933f1] [1328929b-7e15-4693-9a51-9bf180fd314e] [71930338-5fc6-466a-a93d-7b465dfcd6b8] [036f76ec-58e4-420d-9fc2-d3f2b9f78270] [cee13fed-c0b9-442c-a099-3d4fc81ca82f] [09d3d1a3-0eae-453d-beb3-bff29449dc61] [1f17ffc0-f8b0-41e9-ad38-0494f39f11ea] [786bd3cb-2b29-4b17-974f-9ea92bc8da74] [e1d191a4-a7ee-478a-b301-b064e9dc7420] [9ea58dc2-5a95-4dd9-af78-444b5a54ed43] [43b082b6-35f1-45be-ac4e-daca4e4f4ee4] [8babab37-ffbc-4d72-963e-3cc0bcdbed3d] [29b3fd89-3179-4473-8376-7816b176c2e0] [90bcf7f8-fc9c-46c4-a134-299c2211b81b] [a2753a00-ba07-4e1f-81bb-1d0d16b16046] [950c72ef-71d0-497e-a97f-ab3170a98509] [2e759481-5445-4cdb-850e-a161e729a25c] [a68da18b-38ce-4416-9fe1-0c292ab090de] [69a628c5-a444-4eea-8dd1-dacec5fc69ef] [449100af-7496-40d6-97e9-9c32d5251ea8] [2fc7c0f5-4f85-4ea6-8060-f30fac3d4ef8] [27539838-8e9e-4bfe-9a93-7909adf17412] [ec3b7bfa-dcee-40b2-a258-925ef6b8c851] [21958c10-00f5-49cd-a687-ed78cbf87430] [b5fcc168-9dfe-497c-836c-088b5d9eea34] [783997a0-7e27-4d08-a8d0-ec76f446f1bb] [305d2e2d-7473-477b-bde3-bbc4ca63fc99] [7b65baed-2128-4fac-837e-a422757c8588] [006c2e8a-bb4c-4e6d-b007-1c832347a2ac] [f9facdf2-e9c6-4c6b-a532-bc570f82b22b] [61366e67-832d-4237-ad5f-264018fd8936] [2006ddd2-c67f-42af-bde6-80506fc77338] [e88eafaf-ca37-481b-8367-5cf7404b04f2] [f0a9de9e-2c80-488e-9a3e-0d34504d1c92] [523802c6-78d9-428e-8a90-a16704efc2a0] [7718594f-99f3-499e-8019-2c4bfe300b60] [2265d409-1798-42c4-9829-1098803686a3] [51e9d6af-dfbb-44c0-801e-96d6bccecd86] [b012a11b-941e-42c2-b762-37eb709ceacd] [fde0b267-05ed-4b28-9db2-934a7dbe9713] [88961023-e761-46c7-b4da-888e9901b505] [e3b1187f-e3a9-4531-aea8-ebda0d98f987] [aad8ad6a-3164-4bd9-ab18-660ae1901c37] [19363814-5c37-41f6-869e-a23ad35dd9b5] [38409d0a-173b-4c65-bfaa-0e4609d05840] [e28c5649-4df2-43d0-b3c0-3e678117cccb] [d93c5cb8-e032-49f0-a22c-b4bab55287f8] [a56b6355-65ec-4ca0-b305-79f280544625] [b1e7a1e1-d353-496b-8f9d-26c009073145] [b6cb9891-ce6b-4d85-8374-67f766cc168f] [dc482aa1-7a7b-4426-8583-24bb3b9e66a0] [8e71222f-1f3b-4eb2-b7bf-5f652a3e3289] [fde8a64b-951d-4b35-95fb-33d3c096edf2] [cf8ffb6a-f2c1-418a-a8d3-c5e4025958aa] [cc5e02ee-a032-4782-89ed-2f6b6e74dc3b] [7255a0f4-8ca6-4d12-abd3-3eab39c3b42b] [e78436dc-34f7-4e2a-905a-9574565aa893] [51b4c188-9bb7-4b8f-998f-25609092246a] [5c4cf574-6a6e-4851-9f48-fbc93e4eec6f] [f2e91a2c-d7bf-4ac3-81ac-a3773c36ee85] [9c5d8c59-11be-4f24-b05a-182c5daa7a30] [21980f63-4a93-4013-80cb-f5e5eddaa6e0] [4cea332b-4ed6-4cc0-aa5c-f01cecfd01cb] [e123d547-9777-4dd1-b26a-ac44e4ddf0c3] [e117b203-f1d1-4637-b8d3-0130108def52] [6d0cf3e7-049c-43eb-8ce0-a17b7c99aaf5] [c3c2ec80-516f-43ed-bd03-517a6ba04666] [53b44d04-a83b-4240-a931-fb0a94880778] [630c1cdd-d2b2-4de4-ad81-f88b461aa3c4] [e5edd21e-6063-40e2-b25c-6e96b9f6b2ca] [569f7e3b-da8d-49e9-a7f4-eac5baac35be] [7eca15e8-1d69-4f09-85c6-83562e68d685] [434a5856-65d2-447e-a08f-018e24efb78e] [d15dcdaa-2713-4dbc-b465-822b61b3c171] [57144589-d704-4b1a-8d63-fca7ee18fd11] [b9c4c6b7-efc5-473b-847f-1b8209b108ca] [16e832cb-2935-43fc-a51e-7cd72f5bf30c] [03d45e72-5c91-4e83-8b56-35561e4bb824] [80900a8c-a2be-4e3d-b39f-be4582369f58] [0252ccb3-2717-4680-b58d-5ceac4dd0c0a] [9f2d5416-554d-4021-aafa-18151605301d] [f0fa867d-7f44-4d40-8dc8-0aeb52a657c7] [00c112a0-92ec-4f21-aadf-b8af6fedff46] [abac7cbc-400a-4469-b4c7-25a9693a0607] [27344871-95d5-40d2-837e-4913cf9ba895] [04460ffd-d726-4a5a-9416-8110958c8b82] [6491d08b-34b4-4ab1-aa61-e36da96c1f93] [8a8a3372-bd44-4684-a45a-94ef0277475e] [baa75b04-608d-4c63-9a16-9f8c54aecc66] [bc767b9f-1041-4d78-aae6-e09cd7a92474] [d1db0299-4e56-4254-943e-1c779d764461] [40403cd4-0796-414b-b4aa-c15d8ac3f31f] [681eb038-154a-44f2-a670-db5a06d2f959] [6e84c723-de01-43ab-b913-30aebaac0313] [c4061278-f04e-477e-bb7e-1b93fcc99955] [0091db70-1ad1-422e-b7e8-8dde22b26586] [cfa05df7-6d8a-4dd9-bc07-bf5c69eb2f87] [2eb1bba5-a656-45b2-9d27-0c8f7c49fa9c] [90f74a94-112e-4ecb-bae1-1d6dc104b50c] [978b0c35-46a9-4cd1-a71b-5d49942ec66d] [acad3024-29a5-426c-906b-f54fea75c2fb] [38f77642-50a6-452a-99bc-a15570c75d8a] [1f9f44ae-845a-4409-9817-00bb598cfd4b] [1bda79fd-b706-4656-bc44-308dd64441c8] [a80df982-ea69-48c2-baaa-3d1adedae361] [97ae93a0-3ce9-476c-84e4-a957f74be798] [8031a9ad-6a3c-4d93-99fe-fedbd75e41f5] [cbfc3123-de3a-49f7-a87e-ed6b00b136a5] [e7d04697-022c-4fa7-ab77-fe34cb79920f] [5cde8c76-03aa-46f5-8429-2e695fccf687] [ec486ffe-3580-4bf1-83e2-ee193b325f2f] [233ac04e-7d09-41a1-856b-4053eb89646f] [c6f61bc6-2df1-42c2-9c3e-343ed9a64688] [5ef2fe43-09d4-4d2f-a8fb-f8a91e188d2a] [84c8190d-fd7f-478f-8f62-578636f6c0b0] [3898fd8b-ba0c-4989-b26c-c6937d30f0b3] [a2873f93-2035-4d98-83f7-ae3ede42acae] [bb5323ff-b21b-4f8c-b066-33c7cd28c02e] [c5aee9e7-7474-4f5b-b035-a942edc59d96] [79db636b-40d9-432d-8741-d2a6f0659dd5] [443326e1-b3ba-40f1-a2d0-3fb81e3b9344] [c02a27f8-021f-4de9-bee6-d662d80dacf9] [abadb953-e526-45cb-bcf4-16a0c6a893d7] [ea9210af-0fbb-4c71-baa9-79b6e915460c] [1647ed5f-8ea6-491e-8e82-b05e8a99272b] [1768f1ab-d016-42be-8f47-18fce7d18aa0] [d47eb2d9-7347-45d2-b3e2-172cc1c685a1] [d00642f3-4942-41e3-a312-0ee37dce4314] [ff4228ae-2475-4c48-8e51-9e29a5dcf882] [639fef3b-b0a2-43b1-823b-768cac417cdf] [1c1d26e6-385e-4e40-8924-19ad2f25872a] [85947d4e-500d-42e0-858c-529ca453d781] [c79e2fc4-d0f5-4100-b74f-e9edb7893a90] [8d380635-fc76-4818-af70-17b8df1dc936] [fbe15409-82be-436a-bbc5-8152f12c6b5d] [ece6b37a-e54f-431b-a40f-35e6d30a4e08] [7003dfd2-5c81-45fb-a062-e080d6ffd232] [c3b9c728-a43a-406a-958a-0702d1e5e16e] [83b8bd87-b6f7-48a3-849b-3ca9ad2c8238] [c67996b5-3131-403a-b396-aff142dbb161] [d25980d6-b5d3-469d-b91e-1f6893e0c977] [fef2b233-6773-44b2-b799-cf047e22c8a4] [9bf66cea-b6fa-4cd0-9ce6-7357ef525338] [9c57cd98-3d4e-4b85-8bda-26b2c2180afb] [afa347a3-7bc8-46a4-a6bc-12526961e8fa] [4f0547db-dfdf-4d5f-a809-a2cc09e4fce0] [f77c128a-bcf9-4a3a-8261-b9cb76e64cac] [ea84afbf-45ba-45db-997f-32f4f7842ea7] [ec74e9ff-89bf-4635-8d55-d6ad26cf7e2d] [0665c665-6269-4584-9be6-3574c3df77cd] [6d6965e7-8885-408a-a4ee-364f0a8568dc] [15c61151-2bdf-4c10-beaf-d7e7e8853f2c] [1de64870-463f-4336-81aa-9dca91c64314] [36f0332f-a5ea-4ab5-959d-1e12d479df59] [44a4b310-b379-4e29-a3b3-d04f65137117] [ee0220cc-c22e-4d20-a00a-f00131eecd6e] [5e9d886b-b59b-406c-adae-bf4fba09d43f] [96ffc062-9b8e-43d6-a670-2dcee0475afc] [5f930626-f564-479f-8919-d02d3cfa103b] [b447e963-122e-483b-bd70-1566da64edd5] [7cc20c60-a904-43ab-80c8-b8dca96a73b9] [418ce2c0-196d-4f80-ab06-bf02ad5e04b3] [f9936a36-7c51-4612-bc0c-80288f90768a] [e3dd9262-0344-46f2-bad6-8ce8bc23b15a] [fe5d9142-fd5d-418f-a3a5-3213feb245b5] [10dbe406-2d79-40cc-b643-b4b39e2c1236] [fe03b4b9-5ded-4da9-9e48-ff96d3f43744] [d731405f-fa19-4d5a-bae6-611c43358f90] [971ddb3b-6e49-4264-a7c5-0d009972883b] [06538643-33fa-4bbf-80da-0f2a9ce036de] [167f6b23-c2dd-46ff-b938-f1e1defafda8] [b5b55024-7976-4012-afbe-5c2f2f307421] [b769dc7c-3d08-4c29-92d7-348cdc657bb3] [6b8c5e20-abd8-4641-9793-a52ed091250a] [cd1bdbc2-07fb-4c20-8c10-751680fb8db2] [10c142bf-7876-494e-b796-409a21acd215] [a3535a2e-6116-4a37-9dbd-2721f943f130] [0ee87013-db69-4d4e-9e94-c8ffe3478d00] [b3cd2557-7759-4cbd-a2fe-03e4a94fb839] [281ea56e-21d5-4a32-b045-649bcc5d6eb7] [dac1d244-c6bb-4754-996d-d8d286358726] [6623b213-4c22-440d-b18f-59f10a547bb2] [c343e88f-2c91-4414-98e7-1c436e417f91] [43cb9a6c-8f73-4eb9-b0ae-9ee434edcaf7] [03adb347-3bfc-4d88-af50-930a0f09ee66] [5b8bd87a-8818-47d7-9bef-31ae7e35b41e] [714d13f7-5804-48e1-bae1-5a3d36ab081a] [ccbb7d46-7c66-4efb-b5a4-5aa03a1e1541] [7e265980-73c3-448b-ba8f-dd2d41b3cb32] [dd8ad7cd-2905-4dd6-9785-194c55052d80] [30f46370-1ecc-461f-b044-f13e3fd10cf2] [ab70b31a-e48c-4eb5-96e8-0e8c3466b06e] [511e8489-0469-4fab-9479-0577031704a4] [990f3635-d111-486d-a8bb-7d0a2d6a4a5a] [99f6aafd-6cc8-41d6-bfb9-12c9186207b2] [b44ba347-6842-4ef1-a68a-7be669f79673] [c1cda43d-5f9f-43fb-9b48-8a3ea6512e29] [6054dfe9-6fef-4057-a8fa-5622e28479ed] [db4804d8-8711-4854-9fd2-73de1f2fd0db] [494b0fde-f388-4777-b07c-ec63c189de2a] [b769fbce-76ca-4532-b87a-e38029cbf14d] [34087e3d-53d8-49b8-af95-e3edbdac79cb] [1e54d235-1fc7-46bf-b673-6a7470de1c18] [cd726bbe-5703-41ee-b83b-990c196b3535] [200300f7-d105-4880-abf2-e08ac146e125] [e4eff75d-2207-4ab3-a50f-198f80dc47a5] [e8f246eb-e7c7-41f3-82ab-07a5f5c3c43a] [e2992810-0cc7-4006-a5d1-a827bf2c0530] [1473bb6f-926e-46f1-992a-1666df87327c] [b34251f7-4b84-4847-8eed-fdbc11ea998c] [ed658314-5979-495c-a096-d2f673d5e06d] [5b556131-a636-4020-b2f7-56999b91cec9] [035c1dcc-125e-4fba-b86b-b5df93c7378c] [5adce3d9-9a72-4ac1-9155-769d44606218] [7635c3ff-e68c-4ee8-8986-5e8e71b1e7d2] [0f1f6b43-00b4-4153-b608-8a01013a6af8] [21d4c354-845b-49f7-bda7-faaa512bc488] [aaa36b29-429e-4b58-b531-4a874a21055b] [51a2fd84-e405-4cba-aad4-32c558c7224f] [67b2253f-55f0-4e85-abea-9883a64842fe] [eeb9ac47-b661-4672-a89f-b28b46acd740] [89496d0f-ff49-4aa3-923d-cec46214cbe8] [c2855f4e-0cf1-4234-80db-7e1b089834a8] [19aa24cf-b1a3-4a5e-9dd7-8bb8ba73cab9] [2bf0301e-9e96-4db8-9565-a6389043b4be] [3c3d7b2c-6714-44fc-a8f2-357d3681191f] [c0fde6ca-3fec-46eb-803e-5fb737a94af1] [cc002dd7-c46d-4ff2-bd2d-1ad997f92737] [3e721206-a606-4e4d-a88b-862bb52b3471] [c9cd2f12-3b90-4f28-853e-1f9747438a44] [c84b8944-6e8e-45dd-9789-808c2068e1d3] [c50bf920-10f8-457a-bb26-2674d57494a6] [c74b2777-08ed-4301-b4e8-95296c9087f7] [d3d787a6-b06b-4130-86a7-47671bcf333c] [9f2fa9c6-1afe-49a3-874b-d23fa29e3937] [94d25326-4a40-47da-b75a-f9e85d7f21b1] [31c8b33d-e5f1-4c74-a8ad-61ba50bad6de] [afc1560d-149e-496f-9601-92cd040de4e4] [952e0c38-572a-423b-98b0-e1e73d2b4149] [c6df9db6-f562-4d4a-9fde-62a47683d669] [9136cf9e-0693-4fa5-a234-244ba85476f9] [dad90db5-4091-403a-ae7b-672f178b9589] [42998afe-02a3-4bf3-8740-5da0b8c00ae8] [d15e4f2f-a956-4bb5-9fa8-f1c64551683c] [2d755443-23d6-4191-922d-85c7df9a4768] [c27ca8f0-8c20-4b88-bd11-710dfc4f69f8] [93e52ef6-bd8f-425f-b390-30323d6fb835] [b8ff5f30-a9b0-485f-81d5-5c38c9ade01c] [49bf1bd4-6e39-477a-a5e3-d9f47df4c2d6] [20122100-eba8-45be-8263-ed0643e0cfbe] [694e3d94-eb67-4494-9da8-42b5692ae4cf] [9bfef74c-21d4-4c90-85fc-9fe04fefc608] [7a695f28-4282-42e5-93a3-9ac2a2684d87] [d623cecb-2c40-4947-9a5b-f0f4f3654b09] [e65c245f-73a8-4319-b04d-d5eaac3b844b] [06a2550d-63e9-446e-b5fa-beee9b3b3d80] [3ff40741-b117-47b9-b510-039b88349cc8] [e9c5b69a-a74a-420a-9088-a1d5fbda9599] [f1ec9cc0-1f32-4df3-8c9d-90b04fb285c3] [b51f2de7-9edc-4a83-98fa-ef92a9cb7ee2] [609f8ad8-db04-41f7-b431-f73d78387840] [d22ae6b6-571e-4774-ae1f-fdbb4c757a0b] [bfcffd0f-4f3e-40b6-b927-2bba8406e488] [3d64c6b4-743c-437e-83cd-6b14767af24b] [656d8478-fc87-4bf2-b40d-337e10b66da9] [d86f1b04-d8ae-4b84-a5b2-5a7c5d6bd889] [c42f665f-5c10-4756-963d-8322f8b2640d] [61ed54ab-3be7-47e6-8e0f-2a1ade9216b9] [4cc86ad7-43a4-4bf9-9442-0a54876deac4] [04305175-0e73-414e-810d-1e0716321fbd] [7cf0bff2-6083-45e1-8b0b-5ec3e5573f9a] [1466d05a-4934-4c00-8abf-20fc056dd86b] [651d8780-edc8-4cf5-a2eb-0ef10840cfd1] [d11e6964-5d64-425e-9579-72f1d76f46b2] [fa59b02d-ea89-44b5-ac64-898a34dfac15] [8624be85-8885-40f6-bab3-244d37e3a01a] [38c141bd-cb13-4026-9d3e-b2d12a548584] [2a7b7594-1b2e-49ad-bf21-8607714ac1f9] [435a6f65-811a-4b78-a2f7-25b9e698d14a] [24c4a636-26b7-4c32-8ed3-319900c57ecb] [51469288-325a-466a-8286-4a757bb5fd03] [0c008761-d10a-442c-b367-372286b169eb] [88db3bf3-9c24-4226-b1bf-a19792dbf2d4] [39d5186b-a2b6-4821-aaeb-1725a52f43f3] [ab79b49c-77b8-46c3-be8c-0244ad8a092d] [7970cf51-c059-4e14-9f6b-6618ea6bbfb0] [bf531c64-6609-4c96-b219-178f1882b9ef] [4bc9234c-2cd2-49b8-a575-4cf47ef90ab8] [65b1b50d-19ab-4d01-8634-a939fe1c34f4] [c2d44dab-36f4-4c0c-afdf-e6062c81569e] [c43139f5-e536-4a39-868f-df5b2e76b0a5] [19fa242a-8505-48df-b406-8cdf30b382eb] [4e31816c-b3fb-401c-893c-06976c4a60ce] [ecb1e830-bad5-465d-925c-50e237a99749] [ed4b7e42-1c66-4d3b-9054-c1292f72954d] [d5f8d655-574e-426f-9487-e8e8a5604b6b] [49ac5465-adfc-460c-977d-1360a31c45e3] [95b06e18-f460-4f91-abde-52873320e695] [c96bd9ea-c5e1-46eb-b128-cece47d1527e] [2cf21988-f37c-473b-b885-3dce4cd9ec8c] [d8542ae1-8767-41cb-be77-ff1e9f3fa578] [00d174af-96c9-4ac1-8627-44e746a5d229] [175a295f-ecde-44cc-bffb-57a7bbcd2ce6] [0a6dd17f-4d3c-43ba-bd03-0d427e92c118] [1d6d18be-08c8-4aaa-be82-9966165888f8] [c08109cc-eb82-424c-8c0a-4972f5c3b9d5] [ef892291-b1b0-4273-b7ad-042684d9a565] [7ec09196-96d7-49b0-b372-01d242ba473a] [fcb1db22-0bd6-4d64-b325-073ab9e72b9a] [b46db1df-e248-4fad-91ae-89ed6f73672b] [ea7f05e1-5a14-45c9-b8a2-981be6f0d0af] [7bc577d7-7c29-4970-9171-06e44ecdeb4e] [4e8940ea-dcac-4eb8-81c8-b11f776425cf] [be278bb6-b21a-4a10-ab6e-f9fd01fa0f9c] [2c14ff4d-7122-4124-9944-45e46b4e32a9] [4ff8267e-afaf-42c9-9f29-e1ecb0cf2bad] [5625778b-5f94-4658-91a9-be21af81c019] [87a42ba2-6952-4906-86ae-6cca4ec34222] [6b91ee60-0874-4c15-ba00-05913866a3bd] [c32c8b90-d3df-4e78-a3f4-45b46b878d0b] [64ca3ff6-3a0d-4501-a924-b6816a945c02] [edd54556-3528-4df0-99ff-34b2877509b6] [bc881a79-d837-4cbe-afd5-3f889621df46] [2e4bb849-2f23-464f-9a39-a074d7df6928] [d6837e53-1b9a-4735-98a6-95b354c85e51] [69fb1fcb-224f-4a32-9d2a-0a9558f3c695] [5d213b63-36aa-40d2-88ef-6da3e59297cb] [1526984a-c858-4694-b319-623a6305913c] [70a894bd-e6f4-4ed7-8690-5b08a2dd1ecb] [df520471-ec90-4ea2-bd50-11306706533a] [7028b28e-ee11-487b-9a6a-fd577729b0dc] [1d27cd56-8ad4-4932-ad0c-56f99f92b75f] [06c456e4-00f7-4daa-95a9-0bf3ea792d87] [48a8120a-3f08-48bd-aa0e-5aead1cec8aa] [9f13d41b-63d4-4cd4-adf7-3186c1bb50d9] [6fd9a83d-0d","partial_message":"true"}

My environments config file has it in:
config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

If I remove that, then the request logging goes back to normal and no longer has that list of UUIDs in it.
I manually hit a controller endpoint and logged out request.request_id and it has in it:
"action_dispatch.request_id"=>"8f2f673b-4764-4909-b9b3-9161b3f53bad"

There is no actual long list of ids anywhere in the request headers, so why/how is it turning into a long list when config.log_tags is used?
